# Posessive pronouns after a noun?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I seem to recall reading something like *"anguish thine is but a dream"*. The posessive pronoun **thine** is after a noun **anguish** it relates to. Probably, it is from some verse.

I don't encounter such things in normal everyday speech. Is it grammatic, or just a workaround to keep the foot in the verse? If it is grammatic, can I just use any posessive pronoun like that?

Comment: The postpositive pronoun is ungrammatical in modern English, but may occasionally be encountered in phrases such as _brother mine_. That said, nobody is stopping you using postpositive pronouns if you really want to!

Comment: *I seem to recall something like* isn't a lot to go on, is it?

Why not try other possessive pronouns in the same place. For instance, *anguish mine…*.

Please rephrase *keep the foot in the verse*. It has too many meanings…

Comment: Poetry often uses ideosyncratic grammar for stylistic or meter reasons.

Answer (score -2):

Poetic usage aside, the word "thine" is archaic-meaning it is no longer used in Modern English, written or spoken (absolutely not in spoken English).